# Eclipse Editor Problem: It only shows one element instead of whole source code!

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, element

I'm not sure whether it is a feature or a bug: Eclipse Java editor does not show source files correctly. It shows only one Java element (e.g., import, class, method, etc.) which is selected from the package explorer or the outline view.

If it is a feature how can I turn it off and if it is a bug is there any workaround?

Eclipse Version : 3.6.0

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: never heard of that, do you mean whatever file you open it only displays 1 line with the little "+" on the left bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you clicked on the 'Show Selected Element Only' toolbar item. Click again to restore:

[image of where button is http://wiki.eclipse.org/Image:Show_Selected_Element_Only.gif](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Image:Show_Selected_Element_Only.gif)

Source: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Eclipse_FAQs#I_clicked_on_something_and_now_I_can_only_see_the_method_that_I_am_currently_editing._What_do_I_do.3F_Did_I_lose_my_entire_file.3F

Comment: i don't have that button on my 3.6

Comment: Hmm, in that case please provide the screenshot. Press the "prt scr" or "prt sc" screen on your keyboard. Then, open paint and ctrl + v. You will now have a desktop screenshot image. Go to photobucket or imageshack or some image hosting site and load it, and post the URL here so we can see what your settings seem to be like and what the issue could be.

Comment: After a few times toggling the block selection mode and restarting Eclipse, it worked! thanks.